# Using gestures with SpriteKit to Drag, rotate and scale multiple sprite separately at the same time

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, gestures

I have created an iOS app in which I need to be able to move, rotate and scale a sprite ( I am using Apple's Sprite Kit) at the same time. For the most part I have this working. I currently can touch with 1 finger and move the sprite, and if I use two fingers I can scale and rotate the sprite. To do this I am using UIPanGestureRecognizer, UIPinchGestureRecognizer and UIRotateGestureRecognizer. That works fine. What I would like is, while I am dragging, rotating and scaling a one sprite with my right hand, I can take my left hand and drag rotate and scale a different sprite independently of the other sprite.

Currently I am using iOS gestures to move, rotate and scale the sprites. I used code very close to what I found on Ray Wenderlich's website in his Drag and Drop Sprites tutorial for Sprite Kit. http://www.raywenderlich.com/44270/sprite-kit-tutorial-how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites. The part I am using is near the bottom when he start to use UIPanGestureRecognizers instead of just the touch method.

Like I said the Gestures work fine on one sprite at a time. How do I make it work on more than one sprite?

For instance for the UIPanGesturRecognizer I add the code below:

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
      UIPanGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]         initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanFrom:)];
      [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

}

Then I have a method for that called gestureRecognizer below:

```
- (void)handlePanFrom:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

    CGPoint touchLocation = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];

    touchLocation = [self convertPointFromView:touchLocation];

    [self selectNodeForTouch:touchLocation]; // This just returns the node that has been touched


} else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:recognizer.view];
    translation = CGPointMake(translation.x, -translation.y);
    [self panForTranslation:translation];
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:recognizer.view];

} else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

   [_selectedNode removeAllActions];

}
```

}

Finally there is the method that moves the sprite:

```
- (void)panForTranslation:(CGPoint)translation {

if([[_selectedNode name] isEqualToString:kAnimalNodeName]) {

    CGPoint position = [_selectedNode position];
    // Set variable for the point to move selected node
    CGPoint movePoint = CGPointMake(position.x + translation.x, position.y + translation.y);
    [_selectedNode setPosition:newPos];

}
```

}

Now the example code is showing only the methods for the UIPanGestureRecognizer but I also have similar methods for the rotate and pinch gestures. All of this code is in my scene class.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the tutorial you posted pretty much shows how to do it...

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];
    [self selectNodeForTouch:positionInScene];
}

- (void)selectNodeForTouch:(CGPoint)touchLocation {
    //The below statement assigns touchedNode from a sprite that contains touchLocation
    SKSpriteNode *touchedNode = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:touchLocation];

  //2
if(![_selectedNode isEqual:touchedNode]) {
    [_selectedNode removeAllActions];
    [_selectedNode runAction:[SKAction rotateToAngle:0.0f duration:0.1]];

    _selectedNode = touchedNode;

        //the below if statement determines what SKNode is to be given a SKAction
    if([[touchedNode name] isEqualToString:kAnimalNodeName]) {
    SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction rotateByAngle:degToRad(-4.0f) duration:0.1],
                                                  [SKAction rotateByAngle:0.0 duration:0.1],
                                                  [SKAction rotateByAngle:degToRad(4.0f) duration:0.1]]];
        [_selectedNode runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:sequence]];
        }
    }
}
```

So if you want to apply the action to multiple nodes, simply give them the same name. I suggest naming your nodes, put them in an array, and then iterate through them checking if they have the same name.
If you have any further questions please comment.

UPDATE: 1

```
- (void)panForTranslation:(CGPoint)translation {

    //Once again you would do the same thing. Just give the nodes the same name. 
    if([[_selectedNode name] isEqualToString:kAnimalNodeName]) {

        CGPoint position = [_selectedNode position];
        // Set variable for the point to move selected nodes
        CGPoint movePoint = CGPointMake(position.x + translation.x, position.y + translation.y);
        [_selectedNode setPosition:newPos];

     }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have edited my question to try an clarify my question and add some code I'm using. In that tutorial I referenced he actually did the touch 2 different ways. The first which you have listed some code from is using the touches and the second is using UIPanGestureRecognizer which is what I am using as well as UIRotateGestureRecognizer and UIPinchRecognizer. I would really appreciate if you could take a look at my edited question and let me know if you have any ideas. Thanks again for your time. It is so appreciated.

Comment: So you want to apply rotate and pinch to multiple nodes?

Comment: Yes. They should be Independant of each other so that each one can be controlled with different fingers.

Comment: Oooo, ok you want to use UITouch. Read the following link. http://zcentric.com/2008/09/22/multiple-objects-and-uitouch/

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using that tutorial to do something similar. The sample code relies on an instance variable, `selectedNode`, that represents the one node that is selected.

To make this work for multiple nodes, I would recommend using an `NSMutableArray` of selectedNodes, or subclassing `SKSpriteNode` to store whether or not it is currently "selected". Good luck!